# How to combine 2 tags in R+Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have two style modifications in my shiny app on the user side `ui.r`. How do I combine the calls into a single call?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

## Make Lines Black
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("hr {border-top: 1px solid #000000;}")) ),

## Hide the ``logout'' popup
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-server-account { display: none; }'))),

### MORE CODE...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You literally place them both in the same string. For example:

```
css <- "
hr {border-top: 1px solid #000000;}
.shiny-server-account { display: none; }
"
...
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css)))
```